# Determining convergence of $\frac{(x^2)}{x!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine the convergence of the infinite series

$$\frac{x^2}{x!}$$

The factorial clues me in to using the ratio test, but I get stuck when trying to cancel.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

That quotient is equal to $$\frac1{(3x+3)(3x+2)(3x+1)}\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)^6.$$Since$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{(3x+3)(3x+2)(3x+1)}\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)^6=0<1$$your series converges.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

$$S=5\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^6}{(3n)!}x^n$$ can express in terms of hypergeometric functions (do not worry : you will learn about them quite soon).

Making $x=1$ gives the nice
$$S=\frac{5 }{2187 \sqrt{e}}\left(203 e^{3/2}-20 \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+70 \cos
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$ which is
$$1.28786523601314644544347506207\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

As $n \to \infty$ the geometric mean of $(n!)$ goes to $\frac{n}{e}$.

Therefore, the denominator will go to $\left(\frac{3x}{e}\right)^{(3x)} \approx x^{(3x)}$, since $3 \approx e$.

Therefore, you are (*approximately*) evaluating the

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{5x^6}{x^{(3x)}} = 0$.

The easiest way to see this is to compare the two exponents, $(6)$ and $(3x)$.